# I want to show number of row : paginator zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to show number of row : paginator zend framework

**Example:**

```
number   productname     price
1.       pen             25.00
2.       Pencil          10.00
3.       Booklet         12.00
```

i want show number of row the exaple (number row). (get from paginator ok)

Comment: Perhaps it is me, but I am not really sure what you want to do. Could you try to provide more context and explanation?

Comment: Please don't double-post; duplicates will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I can think of three ways you can get current item number from/using paginator:

- using foreach's $key => $item. In this case $key should be your item number.
- using normalizeItemNumber method of Zend_Paginator
- using partialView helper

All the three methods are illustrated in the following example:

**testAction**

```
 public function testAction() {

        $input = array(
            array(
                'productname' => 'somename',
                'price' => 23                
            ),
            array(
                'productname' => 'somename2',
                'price' => 657                
            )
        );

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($input);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);

        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    }
```

**test.phtml** view script

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($this->paginator as $key => $item): ?>

        Item Number (Method 1): <?php echo $key; ?> </br>
        Item Number (Method 2): <?php echo $this->paginator->normalizeItemNumber($item); ?> </br>

    <?php endforeach; ?>                   

    Third Method through partialLoop view helper:
    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('_partials/testPartial.phtml', $this->paginator); ?>

</div>
```

Where **testPartial.phtml** is as follows:

```
<div>
    Item Number (Method 3): <?php echo $this->partialCounter; ?> </br>
    <!-- Other values can be accessed as $this->productname -->
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly, but give this a try

```
$pages = $paginator->getPages();
var_dump($pages);
echo $pages->pageCount;
```

`getPages()` has some useful information in which you can use about the paginator object. It will output something like:

```
object(stdClass)[201]
  public 'pageCount' => int 4
  public 'itemCountPerPage' => int 10
  public 'first' => int 1
  public 'current' => int 1
  public 'last' => int 4
  public 'next' => int 2
  public 'pagesInRange' => 
    array
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 2
      3 => int 3
      4 => int 4
  public 'firstPageInRange' => int 1
  public 'lastPageInRange' => int 4
  public 'currentItemCount' => int 10
  public 'totalItemCount' => int 33
  public 'firstItemNumber' => int 1
  public 'lastItemNumber' => int 10
```

Failing that you might need to do something inside the loop while iterating over the object. For example in your view:

```
$row = 0;

foreach($this->paginator as $rowNumber => $data)
{
    echo "I am row " . $rowNumber . "<br />";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the number in front of the row is not related to the id of the item, you could simply increment a counter through each iteration of your data display.

```
$i = 1;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($this->paginator as $item){
    echo '<li>' . $i . ' | ' . $item['name'] . ' | ' . $item['price'] . '</li>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The very same counter could be used to make a Zebra table (alternating background colors) with the use of modulo.

```
$i = 1;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($this->paginator as $item){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $class = 'even';
    }else{
        $class = 'odd';
    }
    echo '<li class = "' . $class . '">' . $i . ' | ' . $item['name'] . ' | ' . $item['price'] . '</li>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```